# Android 4 - LinearLayout Top and Bottom padding doesn't work

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, padding

I have a LinearLayout with a TextView inside. The problem is that padding is not working correctly on Android 4. I test app on HTC One X emulator Android 4.4.2

My layout:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/msg_body"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:background="@drawable/chat_msg_bg"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingStart="16dp"
        android:paddingEnd="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/user_name"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/user_name"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">
```

Now it looks like this:

[image]

Left and right padding is working, but Top and bottom isn't. What can cause this problem and is there a way to handle this? I've tried to set padding programmatically, but there was no effect. On other OS versions and devices this works fine.

UPD: How it should be:

[image]

Comment: What is you picture suppose to represent ? You posted a code about a Linearlayourt padding and you only show a picture of an isolated widget... From the look of it right now it all looks perfect to me ;-)

Comment: @JasonKrs I've updated the post

Comment: you probably want to set padding to your TextView instead of LinearLayout.

Comment: Seems like you can replace the LinearLayout with a TextView with background and padding...

Comment: @HedShafran Yes, I can replace it, but padding won't work either

Comment: Did you try putting margins on the TextView instead of padding on the LinearLayout?

Comment: @HedShafran yes, it semms like the right way to solve this problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try giving padding pragmatically :**

```
layout.setPadding(left,top,right,bottom);
```

This will take px as parameter. to convert from dp to px :

```
 Resources r = mContext.getResources();
 int px = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(
        TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
        dpmeasure, 
        r.getDisplayMetrics()
);
```

Just remove all padding from XML.

[Reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setPadding%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)

**OR**

> Add margin to textview inside linear layout. and remove padding in
>   linear layout.

Comment: I've used second approach: Add margin to textview inside linear layout. and remove padding in linear layout.

Comment: @BigCoach Ok.. Happy to help :) Happy coding :)

Comment: @BigCoach Actually first one also works. I faced the same issue and i solved it by that. so try it once.

Answer (score 2):

Try removing `android:padding="16dp"` first.
If that don't work try giving the padding to `TextView` not to `LinearLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

Set `android:padding="16dp"` in your `TextView` in `Layout.xml`.